# Issue with Kafka Connect with Solace Source Connector and JDBC SInk Connector

Tags: java, oracle, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, solace

I want to use kafka connect solace source connector with avro converter to push messages to kafka topic. Once messages published on kafka topic, I want to use kafka connect jdbc sink connector with avro converter to push the messages from kafka topic to oracle database. I am able push message from Solace to kafka topic but when I run the sink connector part, it is giving an error -> "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Value schema must be of type Struct".

Below is the config I have:

Solace Source Connector Properties:

```
name=solaceSourceConnector
connector.class=com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
key.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support=true
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support=true
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
kafka.topic=testtopic

#Remaining properties are solace connection related
.
```

JDBC Sink Connector Properties:

```
name=test-oracle
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.user = orcl
connection.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/TESTSERVICE
connection.password = ****
topics=testtopic
auto.create=false
table.name.format=TEST_TABLE1
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
key.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support=true
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support=true
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

After running solace source connector. I can see the messages being pushed in kafka topic. But after running the JDBC Sink Connector I am getting below error:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:560)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Value schema must be of type Struct
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extract(FieldsMetadata.java:82)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extract(FieldsMetadata.java:63)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:78)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:66)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:74)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:538)
```

Kindly help me in understanding where have I gone wrong. Also what can be done to fix the same.

Comment: So to make the scenario work, for now I am not using AvroConverter. I am using ByteArrayConverter for value on the Source part and JsonConverter for value on the sink part. I wrote a transformer and used it in source connector configuration. Under this transformer, I am editing the payload/message received and wrapping it under schema/payload structure to insert into the database table. That worked for now but not the solution I really prefer. So any suggestions are still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think something is happening with your setup or either with your kafka, avro versions. So the sink cannot understand the schema.

Try this setup with Apicurio both to source and sink

```
"key.converter": "io.apicurio.registry.utils.converter.AvroConverter",
"key.converter.apicurio.registry.url": "http://apicurio:8080/apis/registry/v2",
"key.converter.apicurio.registry.auto-register": true,
"key.converter.apicurio.registry.find-latest": true,
```